# jQuery get sending variables as key and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

In my project I am creating a general function which work with various data, and based on that it make ajax get calls. Sometimes I need make get like this:

```
{option1: 'delete', id: idToRemove},
```

and sometimes like this:

```
{option2: 'delete', id: idToRemove},
```

Is it possible to avoid repeating whole function like that:

```
$.get(
    "DB_interface.php",
    {option1: 'delete', id: idToRemove},
    function(data){ ... }
);

$.get(
    "DB_interface.php",
    {option2: 'delete', id: idToRemove},
    function(data){ ... }
);
```

And make this key based on variable ?
Perfect solution will be of course one general $.get funcion like that:

```
$.get(
    "DB_interface.php",
    {VARIABLE: 'delete', id: idToRemove},
    function(data){ ... }
);
```

where VARIABLE is dynamically change variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a json object, and then change its values accordingly:

```
var optionName = "option1";
if( ...condition... )
    optionName = "option2";
var params = { id: idToRemove };
params[optionName] = "delete";
$.get(
    "DB_interface.php",
    params,
    function(data){ ... }
);
```

You can write it shorter, this is just for clarification.

Comment: Yep It works, but my code is shorter. But your is nicer. Catch plus.

Answer (score 0):

Like always... Few minutes after ask question I found solution. 
Working code is:

```
$.get(
    "DB_interface.php?"+VARIABLE+"=delete",
    {id: idToRemove},
    function(data){ ... }
);
```

Leave this here, maybe someone use it in future.